# Prevent SHFILEOPERATION from deleting the target directory

Tags: delphi, winapi

I found example code on stack to use SHFILEOPERATION to delete all the files in a specified directory and it works great. The only problem I have is it deletes the Target directory in the process. I would prefer it if the directory specified for pfrom in the TSHFILEOpStruct remained after all the files it contains are deleted.

I thought By setting the flag FOF_FILESONLY it would only delete files but maybe i'm missing something.

I set my TSHFILEOpStruct to the following:

```
FillChar(FileOp, SizeOf(fileOp), 0);
FileOp.wFunc  := FO_DELETE;
FileOp.pFrom  := PChar(DirName+#0); //Target directory string needs to be Double Null Terminated
FileOp.fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOERRORUI;
SHFileOperation(FileOp);
```

Is there away so set up the TSHFILEOpStruct to accomplish this?

Also I am using Delphi 2007 and I don't have access to all the flags mentioned in the MSDN documentation (FOF_NORECURSION for example)

For convenience here is a link to the aformentioned documentation if needed...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling it to delete the folder itself, so it will.  To delete just the files inside of the folder, you need to use a filename wildcark mask instead, eg:

```
FileOp.pFrom := PChar(DirName+'\*.*'#0);
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it. Even better is to use the simplest wildcard: `PChar(DirName+'\*'#0)`

Comment: I read that in the documentation and thought that was what I had to do but wasn't exactly sure how to implement it. That was just what I needed, a clear example. Thank you Remy Lebeau (Gambit) and David Heffernan.

Comment: In case anyone is interested in the difference between `*.*` and `*`, there isn't one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx

Comment: The documentation for the `FOF_FILESONLY` flag specifically says `*.*` and not `*`.  Whether or not `*` works in this situation is an implementation detail.  I erred on the side of caution and showed what the documentation said to use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Probably the people writing the documentation don't know what they are talking about. But given that's what it says, I guess you are right.

Comment: Same docs also says: Standard MS-DOS wildcard characters, such as "*", are permitted only in the file-name position. Using a wildcard character elsewhere in the string will lead to unpredictable results.